# UPDATE working but not INSERT on live server mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a `PHP/mysql` project on `google cloud` using `bitnami wordpress`. The server type is `MySQL` on google whereas my localhost is `MariaDB`. I am trying to run some `INSERT` queries but they are not working. However, `UPDATE` is working. For example:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO allocations 
          (congregation, mapnumber, name, date) 
        VALUES 
          ('$congregation','$mapnumber','$name','$date'); 

        UPDATE maps 
        SET date='$date', status=1 
        WHERE congregation='$congregation' AND mapnumber='$mapnumber';"
```

The `UPDATE` part works but not the `INSERT`.

I have a few other pages that `INSERT` data into the database but none of them are working. I've read so many "guides" but can't find a solution.

Please help.

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: Please check the mysql permission, whether the mysql user has valid privilege to INSERT.

Comment: @KawaljeetSingh how do I check permission?

Comment: Can you execute only insert statement and check error if any? it will help you to debug it.

Comment: Run the command to see grants . "show grants for [user]"

Comment: Run both statements separately, rather than all in one string, then you can check for an error on each

Comment: @JigneshPatel  I tried error checking but none came up. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. how do I check for error?

Comment: @KawaljeetSingh where do I run that command?

Comment: On mysql CLI or phpmyadmin.

Comment: mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nonexistenttable", $link);
echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n";

Comment: try this `select * from information_schema.user_privileges;`

Comment: @NID I checked the privileges and all are IS_GRANTABLE YES but still doesn't let me insert